# Any reason why a try catch exception would report a file path wrongly in SSIS?

Tags: c#, ssis, bids

So I have this SSIS package that has a script task that is copying files to a destination and then putting their data into C# data structures to parse later.  However, it runs through the first file and then suddenly I get this exception from a try catch in my main method stating:

    `Error: 0x12 at Copy xxx Files to New Destination, there was an exception :< 
    which said: : Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
    Server\130\DTS\binn\xxx370xxxxx_xxx.rpt'.`

the thing that caught my eye is that the file path changed from a different place, I don't store anything in the sql server binn folder...

**Question:**

Could the file path it's trying to read from not be the Bin file and that exception is reporting this folder because of some underlying reason,

**in addition**

Have any good advice for debugging a broken package with C# script tasks?
I am new to this project and don't have much to lean on for figuring it out and debugging C# code in BIDS is seemingly very not intuitive. (doesn't hit breakpoints, can't step through my c# code.)

Comment: It won't be making it up. Your code is trying to find a file there. I would imagine that `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\binn` is a default working folder location and somewhere you are just using a file name instead of a full path.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I'll take a look...

Comment: I'd love to make this the accepted answer. <3

Comment: @MartinSmith , I think you should add that comment as an answer in order to close out this question :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as proposed answer, said below by Martin Smith:

It won't be making it up. Your code is trying to find a file there. I would imagine that C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\binn is a default working folder location and somewhere you are just using a file name instead of a full path.